# How to enable TCP Vegas on Centos 5.4?

Tags: networking, tcpip, tcp

I'm trying to enable TCP Vegas congestion control on Centos 5.4 box. According to Vegas home page it is as simple as `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_vegas_cong_avoid` but this file does not exist.
I found kernel module /lib/modules/2.6.18-164.el5/kernel/net/ipv4/tcp_vegas.ko but insmodding it does not cause the file to appear.
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sysfs interface may have changed since the webpage you've read were written.

Looking at my CentOS 5 box, it seems you might have to do something along the lines of

```
echo vegas > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_congestion_control
```

On kernels newer than 2.6.20 the possible values are listed in `tcp_available_congestion_control`, but I'm uncertain of where/if it's listed for prior kernels.

Comment: Thanks. I also found that loading the mentioned module changes the value of tcp_congestion_control to vegas, but, of course writing to the file is the proper and easier way to do it.

Comment: It's one way of doing it. There's also 'sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=vegas' (which also can be done at boot-time via /etc/sysctl.conf providing the kernel-module have been loaded)